# What is the reputation cap for a day?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

The 'Just jesting' cap says that you need the rep cap for a day. Is this value the same for all sites and what is the value? Is there a list of rep caps that one can access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [faq](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of **200** reputation per day.

Any votes that would increase your reputation past 200 for a given day will have no effect; You are said to have capped out.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that.

Comment: Just to be clear, the rep cap ONLY applies to rep from upvotes. Rep from acceptance of answers (both +2 and +15) and bounties does NOT get limited. Also, see "Mortarboard" badge

Comment: @DVK: I didn't mention that be cause it is irrelevant for the question, as the OP is not concerned with the actual consequences of capping, but with the condition to be met (in order to get hatwarded).

Comment: @bitmask It is relevant in that if you get +18 on your answers, +1 on a question, and 1 "accept" on an answer you posted - you hit +200 rep, but that doesn't hit the cap.